# transform formula given as a string into expression tree and apply to array

Tags: c#

So I have a 'string formula' like this:

```
result = colum1 * colum2
```

coming from an external system. From this 'string formula' I can create an expression tree and apply it to an array as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[,] array = new double[,]
    {
    {1.3, 2},
    {4.5, 4.2},
    };

    // expression: result = colum1 * colum2
    var colum1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double));
    var colum2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double));

    for (int row = 0; row < array.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
    var result = (Expression.Lambda(Expression.Multiply(colum1, colum2), colum1, colum2).
            Compile() as Func<double, double, double>)(array[row, 0], array[row, 1]);
    }
}
```

Is this the most efficient way of applying the formula to each row of the array?

Also how could I translate a 'string formula' dynamically into an expression tree? Admittedly the above is hardcoded. Thanks!

Comment: Of course it's **not** the most effective way  - in fact it's the most inefficient way. Build and compile lambda once outside the loop and use it inside. For the second question, take a look at System.Linq.Dynamic package.

Comment: Thanks please compose an answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider almost anything in .NET not the most efficient by default, but the most efficient in C# would probably be [`unsafe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx) code and parsing the expression yourself.

The easiest way that I know of is with [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression):

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("colum1", typeof(double));
dt.Columns.Add("colum2", typeof(double));
dt.Columns.Add("result", typeof(double), "colum1 * colum2");

var dr = dt.Rows.Add(1.3, 2);
Debug.Print($"{dr[0]} * {dr[1]} = {dr[2]}");  // "1.3 * 2 = 2.6"
```

Comment: Great this fulfills my requirements. It even seems to parse 'formulas' like: ((colum1 * colum2)/3.12) * 10000.123456. Could you please qualify our statement " would consider almost anything in .NET not the most efficient by default" and do you think that the above is one of the fastest ways of applying a formula to a flat dataset in .net?

Comment: AFAIK some of the performance critical parts of [.NET](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) are written in different languages that allow for better optimizations. I could not find any information on this, so I hope someone would correct me if I am wrong. DataColumn.Expression is probably one of the slowest ways to calculate an expression, but I would recommend testing it to see if the difference is significant enough to matter. For better performance, you can check some the Related links on the right.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, is DataColumn.Expression what you used in your answer?

Comment: @csetzkorn Yes, the third parameter of the `Columns.Add` is the Expression.