# fast creation of a calculated column in c#

Tags: c#, .net

Let us say I am being given a 'string' formula from another source. Example:

```
NewCalculatedColumn = (Column1 * Column2)/Column3
```

I would like to apply this formula to create a calculated column for some data stored as double array (or DataTable - I have freedom here) in memory.

In this particular example, the array/dataset consist of 3 column and has thousands of rows. One option is to use DataColumn.Expressions, if the data is stored in a DataTable, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200306/transform-formula-given-as-a-string-into-expression-tree-and-apply-to-array). However, this may not be the most efficient way. Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: let's say we stay with the array. how would you identify the columns? is it an array of arrays of double, or an array of tuples of double, or an array of objects with three/four double members, and is there a way of mapping of "identifiers" (=column names) necessary?

Comment: See webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: index equal-ish column name. example  index 0 => column1, index 1 => column2 etc.

Comment: @jdeng I know this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataTable` is a much heavier data structure than a list of objects (or the more generic `IEnumerable<T>`), as it is indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896238/datatables-vs-ienumerablet).

So, if you are not forced into using a `DataTable` a list of objects that look like the following, can be used:

```
public ObjectType
{
    public double Column1 { get; set; }
    public double Column2 { get; set; }
    public double Column3 { get; set; }

    // avoid division by zero, adjust zero comparison threshold as needed
    // also adjust returned value on zero
    // using C# 6.0 specific syntax. If not available, use get { return } syntax 
    public double NewCalculatedColumn => Math.Abs(Column3) > 0.0001 ?  
        (Column1 * Column2)/Column3 
        : 0.0;
}
```

Even if you fetch data as `DataTable`, you can easily convert it to `List<ObjectType>` as indicated [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30714/converting-datatable-to-list-of-class).

**[EDIT]**

Based on comment, if expression can is dynamic, an external library can be used. E.g. [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/):

```
    public double NewCalculatedColumn 
    { 
        get 
        {
            // you can provide a dynamic expression which contains col1, col2 and col3
            //TODO: add exception handling
            var e = new Expression($"(col1 * col2)/{col3}");
            e.Parameters["col1"] = Column1;
            e.Parameters["col2"] = Column2;
            e.Parameters["col3"] = Column3;
            return e.Evaluate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks makes sense. Challenge is that the formula can be dynamic i.e. everything involving the 3 columns. Example: column1 + column2 + column3

Comment: @csetzkorn - how complex can be your formula?

Comment: It could potentially contain exp, sin, log but your edit is very interesting!!

Comment: @csetzkorn - yes, if you stick to classical mathematical functions, NCalc should be just fine, as indicated [here](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=functions&referringTitle=Home).

Comment: Can one somehow avoid the overhead of creating an Expression for every row?

Comment: @csetzkorn - I think you can initialize the expression outside the property and change parameters values before the evaluation.